# Get the index of object in array using .each

Tags: jquery, each

```js
var data = [{
  "amount": "1",
  "year": "2017",
  "month": "March"
}, {
  "amount": "1",
  "year": "2017",
  "month": "April"
}, {
  "amount": "1",
  "year": "2017",
  "month": "May"
}];

$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, v) {
  console.log(v.index())
  console.log(v.amount)
  console.log(v.year)
  console.log(v.month)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How to get the index of an object that is inside an array using `.each()`

Currently I am using `.index()` but it is not working for me

Comment: just use your "i" variable to get the current index

Comment: index is the first parameter from the function ex:- i

Comment: Have you looked over the `each()` method docs before posting here? In your question I already see you add `i, v` inside the function, which means `index` and `value`.

Comment: You don't need to parse your object here. And, `i` is the index you are looking for.

Comment: @Ionut that is what i missed still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
  "amount": "1",
  "year": "2017",
  "month": "March"
}, {
  "amount": "1",
  "year": "2017",
  "month": "April"
}, {
  "amount": "1",
  "year": "2017",
  "month": "May"
}];

$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  //i is the index and v is the value
  console.log(i);
  console.log(v.amount);
  console.log(v.year);
  console.log(v.month);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i need 9 mins to tick

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need to use `JSON.parse()`.

Secondly, you are already passing *index* and *value* as parameters to the anonymous closure function inside `.each()`

Snippet for your reference:

```
$.each(data, function(i,v){
    console.log("index of object in array: "+i);
});
```